# Is it possible to fully sync Stellar node without history archive access?

Tags: stellar-core, history

The answer to this question might be trivial, since the Stellar foundation history archives might be always available, but I am just trying to understand how the full syncing works.

Could I complete a full sync without downloading the archives just by querying historical ledgers from other peers? If the central history buckets would be abandoned, would it still be possible to fully catch-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **No**.

You are correct: history archives are a required component for the network to function properly; without them you can't even join the network.

See [this document](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#network-level-architecture) for the reasons behind this.